# How to set dynamic for queue, endpoint and message-processor in wso2 ESB

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

I have a table  and my program read table in loop while for call URL and when call completed, i set status OK. Insert to this table doing by other program and the link column is not constant. The table like :

```
    Id   link                        status
==============================================
    1 | 192.168.0.1/adduser?id=1  |
    2 | 192.168.0.2/adduser?id=2  |
    3 | 10.0.0.1/getinfo?id=1      |
    4 | 192.168.0.1/deleteuser?id=10  |
```

so i want to implement each record with a queue, endpoint and message-processor.
for example: 
message-processor1(queue1,endpoint1)

endpoint1="192.168.0.1"

message-processor2(queue2,endpoint2)

endpoint2="192.168.0.2"

message-processor3(queue3,endpoint3)

endpoint3="10.0.0.1"

....

I have not problem for define with static solution but i do not know for define dynamically queue, endpoint and message-processor because new row in table will have new link and i do not like define before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it right, but you can set the queue where you want to send your data by Setting the "TO" Header before sending it. Below is an example.

```
<header xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="concat('jms:/',get-property('queueToSend'), '?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://server1:port,tcp://server2:port)&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&amp;transport.jms.UserName=queuUser&amp;transport.jms.Password=queuePass')"></header>
  <send></send>
```

Comment: Thanks. so how to check queue name exist or not?

Comment: Depends on your broker, e.g. if you use ActiveMQ the queue will be created by the esb at runtime when it doesn't exist. I think you have to give the user you use in esb to connect to the broker, the right to create queues in your broker configuration. The esb will then create that Queue if it doesn't exist